# Triangle inside a cylinder, surface times circumference - hard to visulize question

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

> The surface of the triangle is $X$ and the circumfrence of the base of the cylinder is $Y$.
>
> What is the volume of the cylinder ?
>
> [image]

The answer is $XY$ but why ?

If you'll take the triangle and spin it all the way around the circumference of the cylinder, you'll get the volume of the inner cone. Furthermore, let's build an extra triangle like so:

[image]

Multiply that rectangle by the circumference, we'll get that the volume of the cylinder is: $2XY$ which is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we have:
$$
X = \text{Area of triangle} = rh/2\\
Y = \text{Circumference} = 2\pi r\\
XY = \pi r^2 h
$$
But we also have
$$
\text{Volume} = \pi r^2h
$$
so we see that they are equal.

Comment: I know that, this is not what I asked. My question is when you visualize it you get two different ways for it to appear wrong.

Comment: @GinKin Look at the rectangle you've drawn in your lowest figure (the rectangle of two $X$-triangles). As you "sweep" it around the circumference, you get the whole volume. The mistake is to think that it sweeps $2Y$ all over. It is only the outer part of the rectangle that does so. The innermost part doesn't move at all, and in the middle of the rectangle it moves half the pace. To account for this you have to divide the result by $2$:
$$
V = 2X\cdot Y / 2
$$

Comment: Did you mean to say that 'it sweeps $Y$ all the way' ? (why would it sweep twice ?). About the pace, so because of that there should be gaps as you approach the center ?